# How does a PC make a permanent extradimensional space?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e

In dnd 3.5/pathfinder, how can a PC  make a permanent extra dimensional space? Nothing as fancy nor temporary as a Mordenkainen's Magnificent Mansion but with more legroom than a 20 cubic feet.

The ideal solution would be purchasable and RAW but any suggestion is welcomed (keeping in mind that I will have to convince my DM to allow it).
This is intended for an Eberron campaign but I assume it would be applicable to all dnd/pathfinder settings.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have several different solutions that I'd suggest to this problem.

**[Genesis](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/genesis.htm)**

Genesis is a level 9 Shaper power that creates a new demiplane on the Astral Plane.  Manifest the power, wait a few months, and you have a plane that's a few hundred feet wide, permanent, and shaped however you want it.  You need a way of travelling between planes to get there, but other that, you have a permanent plane that you can access whenever you want.  This isn't quite an extradimensional space, but it has the advantage of being strictly RAW.

**Permanency with Magnificent Mansion**

The only 2 spells in 3.5 that I know of that allow you to make extradimensional spaces are [Rope Trick](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/ropeTrick.htm) and [Mage's Magnificent Mansion](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magesMagnificentMansion.htm).  Rope Trick is clearly insufficient, but Mage's Magnificent Mansion would be at least large enough for what you intend.  Mage's Magnificent Mansion isn't on the normal list for Permanency, but there's no real reason that it couldn't be.  Since it's a level 7 spell, it would probably have a minimum level of 15 and cost 2500 XP (17,500 gp in Pathfinder) to make permanent.

**Permanency with a homebrew spell**

The way I would accomplish this is with a homebrew extradimensional space spell.  Rope Trick, at level 2, is the smallest extradimensional space, which has no actual internal dimensions; it has just enough space to hold the creatures inside it, and no more.  Mage's Magnificent Mansion is at the opposite end of the scale: it's huge, and has nice side effects, but is much higher in level.  For this homebrew spell, I'd put it somewhere in the middle.  I like level 5 for this effect.  5 is where you get Secret Chest, Wall of Stone, and Mage's Sanctum, which are some of the standard "make a secure shelter" spells that are more secure than a locked room.  Here's the spell I'd make:

**Mage's Extradimensional Hut**

Level: Sor/Wiz 5
Components: V, S
Casting Time: 1 Standard Action
Range: Close
Effect: Extradimensional mansion, up to 1 10-ft. cube/level (S)
Duration: 2 hours/level (D)
Saving Throw: None
Spell Resistance: No

You conjure up an extradimensional dwelling that has a single entrance on the plane from which the spell was cast. The entry point looks like a faint shimmering in the air that is 4 feet wide and 8 feet high. Only those you designate may enter the mansion. You may open it again from your own side at will. The atmosphere is clean, fresh, and warm.

You can create any floor plan you desire to the limit of the spell’s effect.  The place is unfurnished, and any walls are made of bare wood or stone, your choice.

Since the place can be entered only through its special portal, outside conditions do not affect the mansion, nor do conditions inside it pass to the plane beyond.

This spell can be made permanent with the Permanency spell.  It has a minimum caster level of 9, and costs 500 XP (2,500 gp in Pathfinder).

Comment: This is excellent, thank you. Could you possibly add monetary cost considerations please?

Comment: The psion can to to the demiplane upon manifesting Genesis.

Answer (score 11):

*Note:* This answer uses *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* and emphasizes employing spells; *Pathfinder* and *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*'s psionics and other special abilities make available further options.

---

I know what you're looking for.

**You want an extradimensional space** (so folks using the spell [*scrying*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/scrying.htm) [div] (*Player's Handbook* 274-5) *et al.* may well *find* you but nonetheless can't *reach* you using the spell [*teleport*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/teleport.htm) [conj] (*PH* 292-3) *et al.*, and so you don't have to carry all your loot with you and so *you never pay for an inn stay again*) **that maintains changes you make to it** (so you can build immovable objects or traps or whatever in it and have those still exist when you revisit the space) **that you can journey to safely instantly** (maybe as a standard action or less) **and where you can stay indefinitely** (so it must have, like, *air*).

That's pretty much what *every* serious adventurer wants: an instantly accessible secure, private, comfortable lair. If that's the *only* acceptable option, skip to You Want Your Own Demiplane and do that, but...

## If Doing Without Is Acceptable

Besides the 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell [*rope trick*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/ropeTrick.htm) [trans] (*PH* 273) and the 7th-level Sor/Wiz spell *Mordenkainen's [magnificent mansion](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magesMagnificentMansion.htm)* [conj] (*PH* 256), in *D&D 3.5* there're a few other items and spells that can make a livable extradimensional space.

- A *[portable hole](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#portableHole)* (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 264) (20,000 gp; 0 lbs.) has approximately 283 cu. ft. in which to, um, hole up. That's a lot less than it sounds if one wants to live in it--considering the square footage comes from the *hole* being a 6-ft.-diameter, 10-ft.-deep cylinder--, but reasonable if one's a Small creature. Solve the only-10-min.-of-air problem with a [*necklace of adaptation*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#necklaceofAdaptation) (*DMG* 263) (9,000 gp; 0 lbs.). Ask the DM if the *hole*'s interior can be modified. *Note:* The *hole*'s entrance still exists on the Prime, so it requires *either* a trusted minion *or* a safe place to camp anyway.
- An *enveloping pit* (*Magic Item Compendium* 159) (3,600 gp; 0 lbs.) is, perhaps, *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*'s best deal: A *portable hole*-like item but having a 10-square-ft. entrance and being *fifty feet deep!* A spiral staircase and some landings is all it takes to build a lair inside an *enveloping pit*. Limited to LE, LN, and NE alignments, a Use Magic Device skill check to emulate an alignment (a not inconsequential DC 30) will clear that hurdle.<sup>1</sup> Ask the DM if the the 10-min.-of-air thing *is* still a thing, as the *pit* "functions like a *portable hole*," and, of course, if the *pit*'s interior can be modified. Note:* The *hole* still exists on the Prime, so it, too, requires *either* a trusted minion *or* a safe place to camp anyway.
- A *minor schema of pocket cave* [conj] (*Champions of Ruin* 33) (5th-level spell at caster level 9) (*Magic of Eberron* 122) (18,000 gp; 1 lbs.) grants the bearer, who'll probably need to make a Use Magic Device skill check (DC 29) to activate it,<sup>2</sup> the ability to create 1/day for 9 hours a dark, wet, comfortable (with air, even!) cave stocked with fresh water and edible fungi that's made up of 18 10-ft. cubes with entry restrictions like the spell *Mordenkainen's magnificent mansion*. *Note:* It's just a *mansion* for lower-level folks that's available sooner but, often, harder to use.

Although not of much use to some creatures and sometimes only available to high-level creatures, other more obscure options exist (e.g. the 8th-level Sor/Wiz spell *Mordenkainen's capable caraval* [conj] (*Stormwrack* 119) has an extradimensional space within the conjured ship like that of the spell *Mordenkainen's magnificent mansion*, the 9th-level creation Domain (*Spell Compendium* 153) spell *pavilion of grandeur* [conj] (*SpC* 272), a *camouflaged compartment* (*Dragon* #352 80) (12,000 gp; 0 lbs.) in a warforged buddy may with the DM's permission permit Tiny creatures to use the 10 cu. ft. therein as a lair, undead and other nonliving creatures can lair in the *dragonskin bag of Grendel* (*Dragon* #329 26) (18,000 gp; 8 lbs.) although the *bag*'s interior isn't extradimensional).

If not using these--or if these just aren't up to your exacting standards--,

## You Want Your Own Demiplane

Any creature with an Intelligence score of at least 3, using the core rules alone, with some careful planning and a lot of gp, can have his own demiplane and permanent, ready access to that demiplane.

#### Step 1: Acquire the Ability to Cast the Spell *Genesis*

The 9th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*genesis*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/spells/genesis.htm) [trans] (*Epic Level Handbook* 117) allows the caster, while on the Ethereal Plane, to create a 1-ft.-radius demiplane which grows at the rate of 1 ft. per day until its a 180-ft. radius demiplane; casting the spell again on the demiplane increases demiplane's size again.<sup>3</sup> The caster "determines [the demiplane's] factors such as atmosphere, water, temperature, and the general shape of the terrain," but whether this includes the plane's [time](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/planes.htm#time) and [magic](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/planes.htm#magicTraits) traits (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 148 and 149-50, respectively) is the subject of vicious Internet debates.

Anyway, the spell *genesis* can be cast by a creature capable of casting 9th-level Sor/Wiz spells, or a non-caster can cast the spell by employing magic items, such as the ones below.

- A *scroll of genesis* (9th-level spell at caster level 17) (28,825 gp; 0 lbs.). Unless the spell *genesis* is on the creature's spell list, the creature must first employ the skill Use Magic Device to decipher a scroll (DC 34) then the skill Use Magic Device to use the scroll (DC 37).
- A *staff of genesis* (9th-level spell at caster level 17) (1,365,050; 4 lbs.). Unless the spell *genesis* is on the creature's spell list, the creature must employ the skill Use Magic Device to emulate the class feature Spells of a class that has the spell *genesis* on its spell list (probably DC 37). *Note:* If the DM is using the rules for Used Wands (*Magic Items Compendium* 227), a case can be made for used staffs. A *staff of genesis* with 1 charge costs 27,595 gp.<sup>4</sup>
- Outside of core, an *attuned gem of genesis* (9th-level spell at caster level 17) (33,100 gp; 0 lbs.). Deliberately touching the *gem* to activate it casts the spell once. *Note:* Created *via* the feat Attune Gem (*Magic of Faerûn* 21), this has the advantage of the user not needing to make Use Magic Device skill checks. This has the disadvantage of being the product of an obscure, unupdated feat in a *D&D 3E* source book for the Forgotten Realms campaign setting. But, *still*, it *exists.*<sup>5</sup>

Paying a caster to just *cast* the spell *genesis* costs 26,530 gp but such a service, according to Table 7-8: Good and Services (*PH* 128-9) under Spellcasting and Services, "is not generally available except by DM's permission" (129). A fully charged *staff of genesis* isn't even available in a planar metropolis (*ELH* 113), but the other items above may be available in towns at least the size of a large city (*DMG* 137).

#### Step 2: Cast the Spell *Genesis*

The spell *genesis* can *only* be cast on the [Ethereal Plane](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/planes.htm#theEtherealPlane) (*DMG* 151-2). If the DM's campaign uses an alternate planar cosmology, it's possible the caster's boned. Ask first.

1. A Knowledge (the planes) skill check may determine the best place on the Ethereal Plane to cast the spell *genesis*, but the check's DC will depend on the DM. This is actually important (see 3, below), and it may be worth investing resources into improving this Knowledge (the planes) skill check.
2. The caster employs a method of planar travel to journey to the Ethereal Plane. For a caster, the 5th-level cleric spell or 7th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*plane shift*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/planeShift.htm) [conj] (*PH* 262) *et al.* is the obvious choice, and available to non-casters in a variety of forms (e.g. attuned gem, minor schema, scepter, staff). Note that the 7th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*ethereal jaunt*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/etherealJaunt.htm) [trans] (*PH* 227-8) and the 9th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*etherealness*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/etherealness.htm) [trans] (*PH* 228) are--without a generous DM (see footnote 5)--insufficient for the task that awaits.

   The DM may mandate that the caster of the spell *plane shift* needs the appropriate forked rod for the Ethereal Plane--the spell *plane shift*'s material component--, necessitating *another* quest. A more lenient DM has his campaign's spell component pouches contain such forked rods as they are without a gp value. Ask first. (The 5th-level Psion/Wilder power *psionic plane shift* [psychoportation] (*Expanded Psionics Handbook* 124) needs no material components, making that power in some campaigns more efficient than the traditional spell *plane shift*.)

   In core only, a non-caster without the skill Use Magic Device can still access the Ethereal Plane alone, but it's *either* expensive and, if one has a low Intelligence score, risky *or* just risky if one is not of a good alignment.

   - The [*figurine of wondrous power* (obsidian steed)](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#obsidianSteed) (*DMG* 256, 257) (28,500 gp; 0 lbs.) creates 1/week for up to 24 hours, a creature under the activator's control that can, among other things, 1/round at will use an effect like the spell *plane shift*. A good-aligned activator who has the creature use this ability may (10%) end up in the Nine Hells instead of his intended destination.
   - An [*amulet of the planes*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#amuletofthePlanes) (*DMG* 247) (120,000 gp; 0 lbs.) grants the use the ability to use at will an effect like the spell *plane shift*. If the user fails an Intelligence ability check (DC 15), he *either* ends up in a random location on the desired plane (01-60) *or* on a random plane (61-00). *Note:* ["The normal take 10 and take 20 rules apply for ability checks"](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/usingSkills.htm#taking20) (*PH* 65), so a creature with an Intelligence score of at least 18 can use the *amulet of the planes* fearlessly if not under stress.
3. If not already there, travel to the appropriate Ethereal Plane location (see 1, above) and cast the spell. The spell *genesis* has a casting time of 1 week. Interruptions while casting the spell can cause the spell to fail, so the caster will probably need sequestration and maybe friends, mercenaries, or competent minions for protection while he casts (and getting them to the Ethereal Plane or acquiring them while on the Ethereal Plane is possibly yet *another* quest). When the spell's completed, the demiplane is created.

Casting the spell *genesis* merely creates the demiplane.<sup>6</sup> The spell *doesn't* move the caster to the demiplane (which is okay; it's only 2 ft. in diameter). The caster, in fact, doesn't even absolutely--really, *really*--know the demiplane *exists* until he visits it.

#### Step 3: Acquire Means to Journey to and from the New Demiplane

This is harder than it may seem. A generous DM will allow the creator knowledge of the size and metal type of the forked metal rod necessary to access the plane *via* the spell *plane shift* (again, advantage to the power *psionic plane shift*), maybe even including the rod in the campaign's spell component pouch. A stricter, by-the-book DM may say that, as a *new* demiplane, such knowledge doesn't yet exist and will have to be discovered (still a *further* quest). Once (or *if*) the forked metal rod appropriate to the demiplane is acquired, though, the spell *plane shift* can be used for quick access.

In core, if the rod knowledge can't be acquired, the caster's stuck using the aforementioned *amulet of the planes* or *figurine of wondrous power* (obsidian steed). Alternately, there're these:

- A 9th-level githyanki (*MM* 127-8) cohort can be recruited--with the DM's permission--by a creature who takes the feat [Leadership](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#leadership) (*PH* 97, *DMG* 106), is at least level 13, and achieves a leadership score of 16. The cohort has, as a spell-like ability usable once per day, *plane shift*.
- The [*cubic gate*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#cubicGate) (*DMG* 254) (164,000 gp; 0 lbs.) grants the bearer the ability at will to *either* open a gate to a random spot on 1 of 6 different planes (including the Prime) *or* transport himself and adjacent creatures to a random spot on 1 of 6 different planes (including the Prime). (The spot's random, not the plane.) The item's creator "should choose the planes to which the other five sides are keyed," and this can include the newly created demiplane. *Note:* A *staff of plane shift* (5th-level spell at caster level 9) (34,050 gp; 4 lbs.) is usually a better investment if one has ranks in the skill Use Magic Device, but if one's a mundane good creature with a low Intelligence score and no ranks in the skill Use Magic Device, the *cubic gate*'s a thing. Unless cash and ambition's outweighed sense, the demiplane's only 360 ft. in diameter. Barring horrible topographical errors on the part of its creator, a random spot on the demiplane shouldn't be a big deal.

Outside of core, magical, nonpsionic methods abound of journeying to the demiplane (e.g. *circlet of convocation*<sup>7</sup> (*Dragon Compendium Volume 1* 133-4) (4,775 gp; 0 lbs.), *dimensional chalk holder* (*Arms and Equipment Guide* 131) (22,950 gp; 0 lbs.), *lesser amulet of the planes* (*Dungeon* #107 69) (24,000 gp; 0 lbs.), *planar ring gates* (*Planar Handbook* 83) (20,000 gp; ea. 20 lbs.), an ur'Epona<sup>8</sup> (*PlH* 72, 130-1) (32,000 gp and 5 gp/day)).

#### For the DM

The prices and events above are for PCs. NPCs who do the same should, by the time they're encountered, have their full complement of gear back after making their extradimensional bolthole. NPCs still pay for the means of getting to and from the demiplane out of their current wealth but should *not* pay for creating the demiplane using their current wealth--the DM should factor that into the creatures' Challenge Ratings or the encounters' Encounter Levels. According to Table 4-23: NPC Gear Value, a *very* careful level 13 NPC could pull this off, but it's more likely an accomplishment of at least a level 15 NPC.

---

**Notes**

1. Faking out the *pit* to use its relic power requires a creature of the appropriate alignment to make a Use Magic Device skill check to emulate the cleric class feature deity, Domains, and Domain spells (the first line of which is, "Choose a deity for your cleric" (*PH* 32)) (DC 21) then to make a Use Magic Device skill check to emulate cleric class feature spells (DC 29) to expend a nonexistent 5th-level spell slot to activate the *pit*--like Lidda uses channel energy to activate the magic chalice (*PH* 86). Ask the DM first, though.
2. I know it's bold, but most folks don't take the feat Initiate of Gruumsh (*CR* 24).
3. While it's cheaper to use the 9th-level cleric spell *word of genesis* [conj] (*Tome of Magic* 262), the spell's more obscure and will likely require additional resources so the caster can make the Truespeak skill check (DC 50). The demiplane it creates also grows at an *achingly* slow pace and has different effects. It's worth comparing the two, though.
4. "You know," thought [Emirikol](http://akraticwizardry.blogspot.com/2010/09/on-trail-of-emirikol-chaotic.html) [the](http://batintheattic.blogspot.com/2010/09/imagining-d-for-myself.html) [Chaotic](http://batintheattic.blogspot.com/2010/09/more-on-emirikol-chaotics-ride.html), "after that 49th demi-plane, I'm done. I think it's time to put my *staff of genesis* with 1 charge up for sale." *Really?*
5. My advice assumes the DM sanely house rules that attuned gems *don't* instantly cast the spell upon activation (it doesn't say either way, but it's implied they *do* in the rules for Gem Magic (*Mag* 113-4)). If the DM rules spells are cast immediately no matter what their normal casting times, this is *totally* worth the extra 5,000 gp... and makes the feat Attune Gem *awesome.*
6. Yes, *merely*.
7. Park a buddy in the demiplane, leave, use the spell [*sending*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/sending.htm) [evoc] (*PH* 275-6) to tell the dude to cast the spell [*scrying*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/scrying.htm) [div] (*PH* 274-5) on you, detect the sensor, and use the *circlet*'s *plane shift* effect to go to him. Easy.
8. The ur'Epona can replace the [celestial](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/celestialCreature.htm) [riding dog](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/dogRiding.htm) (*MM* 31, 272) of a caster who can cast the spell [*summon monster II*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/summonMonsterII.htm) [conj] (*PH* 286, 287).

Comment: Ummm, why aren't the item crafting rules option mentioned, out of curiosity? Craft an item based off the appropriate effect and make it continuous, and presto, instant portable continuous usable almost anywhere extra-dimensional space.

Comment: @nijineko The process above exists independent of the DM. So rather than having to approve an original magic item and set that original magic item's price, the DM must say instead that process above for whatever *won't* work. Does that make sense?

Comment: ( ^-^)b    .......I get it. While I prefer to include such options for completeness, I can see the logic you are using there.

Comment: @nijineko Also, be kind: note the answer's date. Were I to've written it more recently, it might've address the original magic item idea. However, even now that's still not a solution I'm fond of, especially when what's asked can already be done by just using the rules.

Comment: Oh, hey, there are dates! Never really paid attention to that before you pointed it out. If you hadn't guessed by now, I usually just read over the answers and then reply whatever happens to pop into my head.

Comment: It's not worth the edit to note that using an *enveloping pit* as a deeper *portable hole* doesn't mandate any particular alignment, deity, or feat, but to use its relic power—as is typical—one must somehow meet the strict requirements of the *pit*. O, and the summoned creature can't use its *plane shift* abilities. Huh. Maybe I should edit this 6-year-old answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a *Planeshifter* Arcane Prestige class in the Manual of the Planes.  This class is cool and can grow there own demi plane at normal (i.e. not epic) levels.  You can enter it at 6th level at which point they can Planeshift as an ability (they can do this at will at 13th level!).    At 15th level they can grow there own Demiplane - a pocket dimension that the Planeshifter can determine the landscape for at time of creation.  Also the Plansehifter can move materials from any plane to another at 14th level allowing them to move say a Tower and furniture etc. there from the Prime or any other plane for that matter.  Manual of the Planes page 31.

Answer (score 1):

One answer not mentioned is dreams. In many game cosmologies dreams exist as real places and are viable places to travel to. Be careful though, if you make your base in a dream [Night Hags](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/nightHag.html#night-hag) and other monsters could attack.

Pathfinder gives a very simple and easy way to travel to a dream you've created via the [Diadem of Nod](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/mythicAdventures/mythicItems/artifacts.html#diadem-of-nod).

Most probably there are more ways to create dream realms (such as mind controlling victims) but I am not very familiar with DnD 3.5 or Pathfinder and the exact ways to achieve this.