# Genesis spell clarification and Placing gates in portable holes

Tags: dnd-3.5e, planes

I'm building an artificer for an upcoming 3.5 campaign but Campaign will have very little downtime for crafting.

My idea is to create a Demiplane that has a timeline out of sync with the material plane.

I did find the spell Genesis but it doesn't say the creation does or doesn't include tkme. Just to visualize the environment.

Would this spell allow me to make a fast time Demiplane?

Is there another spell I should use instead?

I also want to have this plane accessable via a portable hole. Without the whole singularity death thing.

Comment: The limits of the spell *genesis* are discussed [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60176/8610) and making one's own demiplanes is discussed [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/47182/8610). With those in mind, is there something in your question that's unaddressed by those two questions and their answers?

Comment: I didn't see those post. Feel free to close, I've got my answer now

Comment: Actually, I'm hesitant to do that. There are several questions here, the biggest of which is in the title and the lesser of which is *Can I turn a* portable hole *into a portal to a demiplane?* If you want to narrow this question to either of those, that's cool.

Comment: Zakier, what answer did you come up with? Was it "no, you can't use Genesis"? Did you find a way to do it? Via a portable hole?

Comment: Well as far as the Demiplane is concerned, the ability to determine its time is either DM decision or create an epic Genesis spell in which it functions the exact same as Genesis but with more clarification it's abilities.

Comment: As far as the gate goes the item description only specified bags of holding being placed it and vice versa with the action in question being placed. Meaning it goes from outside in. By my thinking create the gate while inside the portable whole and there is no"threshold crossing" to activate the effect on a singularity. Plus it isn't a singularity but instead a portal created to the astral plane

Comment: Looks like you now know enough to answer your own question. Maybe you even earn the [self-learner](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/self-learner) badge.

Comment: Might be a good idea to try. I'll transfer over what I've learned through research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through extensive research, as far as the Demiplane is concerned, the ability to determine its time is either [DM decision](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60176/what-are-the-limits-to-the-genesis-power) or create an [epic Genesis](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47182/how-does-a-pc-make-a-permanent-extradimensional-space) spell in which it functions the exact same as Genesis but with more clarification it's abilities.

However, if including third party material, specifically the book Chronomancy: The power of time, A chronomancer, having physically seen time, would be able to visualize time as an environment and thus able to speed up time in a created Demiplane when executing the Genesis spell.

As far as the gate part is concerned. That is actually raw.

In Dragon Magazine Guide #221 Article 101 *uses of portable hole* we see that:

> 42) Set up a permanent gateway to another plane inside the hole.

So that answers that question.

Permanent access to a permanent gate to a Demiplane that may or may not have the flowing time trait.

Not to mention a very handy getaway location as it's already stated that a portable hole can be picked up from the inside.

From the item details:

> This hole can be picked up from inside or out by simply taking hold of the edges of the cloth and folding it up. Either way, the entrance disappears, but anything inside the hole remains.