# Is creating a Dimensional Plane possible in 5e without DM fiat?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, planes

I'd like to create a dimensional pocket inside my armored wagon. Duration should be permanent, but if that's not possible longer lasting is better. It would be fine if I have to refuel it every so often.

Can wizards go about doing this, or is it up to DM fiat now?

I'm used to being able to do this in [older editions through magic item creation or the spell *Genesis*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47182/how-does-a-pc-make-a-permanent-extradimensional-space).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Permanent is hard.** A portable hole, glued to the floorboards, might be about the best you can do.

**But you can do sort-of-permanent:** *Demiplane*, the 8th-level spell, should serve you well. The portal's only open for an hour at a time, but you can re-cast to access the same extra-dimensional space if you like (PHB p.231). So the stuff is stored in a ~permanent~ extra-dimensional space, but your access portal is transient. (But that may even be better!? Just make sure to protect your wizard.)

**Other options:**

*Mordenkainen's Magnificent Mansion* will do the same thing at a lower level, but the duration's not great. (Because you can only store stuff for the spell's duration of 24 hours. But you can have a nice time doing so!)

*Handy Haversack*s and the like nominally fit the bill, but probably aren't what you're looking for.